# Calculating monthly retention

Tags: python, pandas

I've been performing a cohort analysis for a SaaS company, and I have been using [Greg Rada's](http://www.gregreda.com/2015/08/23/cohort-analysis-with-python/) example, and I ran into some trouble looking up a cohorts retention.

Right now, I have a dataframe set up as:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import sys
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

pd.set_option('max_columns', 50)
mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2

%matplotlib inline

df = DataFrame ({
  'Customer_ID': ['QWT19CLG2QQ','URL99FXP9VV','EJO15CUP4TO','ZDJ11ZPO5LX','QQW13PUF3HL','SIJ98IQH0GW','EBH36UPB2XR','BED40SMW5NQ','NYW11ZKC8WK','YLV60ERT0VT'],
  'Plan_Start_Date': ['2014-01-30', '2014-03-04', '2014-01-27', '2014-02-10', '2014-01-02', '2014-04-15', '2014-05-28', '2014-05-03', '2014-02-09', '2014-06-09']
  'Plan_Cancel_Date': ['2014-09-19', '2014-10-29', '2015-01-19', '2015-01-21', '2014-08-19', '2014-08-26', '2014-10-01', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-23', '2015-09-02']
  'Monthly_Pay': [14.99, 14.99, 14.99, 14.99, 29.99, 29.99, 29.99, 74.99, 74.99, 74.99]
  'Plan_ID' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
})
```

So far, what I have done is...

```
df.Plan_Start_Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Plan_Start_Date)
df.Plan_Cancel_Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Plan_Cancel_Date)
#Convert the dates from objects to datetime

df['Cohort'] = df.Plan_Start_Date.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
#Create a cohort based on the start dates month and year

df['Lifetime'] = (df.Plan_Cancel_Date.dt.year - 
df.Plan_Start_Date.dt.year)*12 + (df.Plan_Cancel_Date.dt.month - 
df.Plan_Start_Date.dt.month)
#calculat the total lifetime of each customer

df['Lifetime_Revenue'] = df['Monthly_Pay'] * df['Lifetime']
dfsort = df.sort_values(['Cohort'])
dfsort.head(10)
#Calculate the total revenue of each customer
```

I have tried to Create a retention column from the Plan_Start_Date, similar to how Greg structured his:

```
dfsort['Retention'] = dfsort.groupby(level=0)['Plan_Start_Date'].min().apply(lambda x: 
x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
```

But that would just repeat the value of the ['Cohort'] on my dataset.

And in turn, when I try to create an index hierarchy to map out retention by:

```
grouped = dfsort.groupby(['Cohort', 'Retention'])
cohorts = grouped.agg({'Customer_ID': pd.Series.nunique})
cohorts.head()
```

instead of looking like:

```
                  Total_Users 
Cohort  Retention
-------------------------------
2014-01  2014-01        3
         2014-02        3
         2014-03        3
         ...
         2015-01        1
2014-02  2014-01        2
         2014-02        2
```

It looks like:

```
                   Total_Users 
Cohort  Retention
-------------------------------
2014-1  2014-1        3
2014-2  2014-2        2
2014-3  2014-3        1
...
```

I know I am grouping wrong, and creating the retention column, but I am at a loss on how to fix it. Anyone able to help a rookie out?

Comment: df.groupby(level=0)['Plan_Start_Date'].min().apply(lambda x: 
x.strftime('%Y-%m')) why we need groupby here ?

Comment: From my understanding, don't I need it for grouping on the index?

Comment: This link should be useful: [Link](https://medium.com/@darshildesai/user-retention-in-python-8c33fa5766b6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multi_indexing and then grouping on 2 columns.

```
dfsort = dfsort.set_index(['Cohort', 'Retention'])
dfsort.groupby(['Cohort', 'Retention']).count()
```

However, in your data, you only have one 'Retention' date for each cohort, which is why you don't see different Retention dates.

```
Cohort  Retention
---------------------
2014-01    2014-01  
           2014-01  
           2014-01  

2014-02    2014-02
           2014-02
```

Maybe you want to look at how you calculated the Cohorts and Retentions.

Comment: I see your point. The way the cohort is calculated is correct, since its tracking the first moment that customer has joined. However, I think I need to create the 'Retention' from the Plan_Start_Date and then do a datetime range to match the total Lifetime of each customer, and then groupby the way you did. Will update you on the results.